# How to debug 'Desktop' libgdx application in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

Setting configuration to Android on Android Studio I can easily debug by running 
**debug 'android'**

Unfortunately  setting configuration to desktop and running **debug 'desktop'** doesn't seams to work. It only display the following message without stopping at the break points

> Listening to connection, address 127.0.0.1:55558, transport 'socket'

Can someone help?

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy - everything is describe here in libgdx page:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation/gettingstarted/Running%20and%20Debugging.html#running-desktop-project-in-intellij-android-studio

Short version:

- You should run app by DesktopLuncher class
- If app crash - check your run configuration your asset folder. It is probably wrong. Set correct folder and everything should work good :).